# Remove list item by class name using PHP

Tags: php, domdocument

I am trying to remove a parent list item when the child link has a class 'hide'. How would I get the class name and then remove the parent 'li' if a child within it has a the 'hide' class?

```
$html = '<ul> 
    <li><a href="/first">First Item</a></li>
    <li><a class="hide" href="/first">First Item</a></li>
</ul>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('li') as $tag){
    // Check if there is a hide and remove the parent list item
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) in conjunction with `DOMDocument`. Try the following:

```
<?php

$html = '<ul>
    <li><a href="/first">First Item</a></li>
    <li><a class="hide" href="/first">Second Item</a></li>
</ul>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$elements = $xpath->query('//a[@class="hide"]/..');

foreach ($elements as $el) {
    $el->parentNode->removeChild($el);
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Yields:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/first">First Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

The XPath expression `//a[@class="hide"]/..` will match any `<a>` tags containing the "hide" class, and `/..` returns its parent. So you are returning the parent node of any match; i.e: the parent `<li>` of any match, in your example.

Finally, we iterate over all matching `<li>` elements and remove each one from its parent node.

Here's more information on [`DOMXPath::query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php)

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

As i understand you need to delete the first li from the ul based on a class name of the internal a element; Here is a solution

```
  $html = '<ul> 
        <li><a href="/first">First Item</a></li>
        <li><a class="hide" href="/first">First Item</a></li>
    </ul>';

    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

    $elements = $xpath->query("//ul/li/a[@class='hide']/parent::*/preceding-sibling::*[1]");


    foreach($elements as $node) {
      $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    };
    echo $doc->saveHTML();
```